# Rename file name

Tags: python, file-rename

Here is my code :

```
import os
def rename_file ():
    file_list = os.listdir (r"C:\Users\Sushant\Desktop\test")
    print (file_list)

    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None , "0123456789" ))

rename_file ()
```

result :

```
os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(None , "0123456789" ))
TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

Why do I keep getting this `error` ? I have just kept a file with some numbers and want to remove it .

Comment: Remove None from the translate arguments

Comment: You should read compiler errors more carefully, it is all written there: it complains that translate function takes exactly one argument, but you are trying to pass two `translate(None , "0123456789" )`

Comment: Actually, `string.translate` can take two arguments, as stated here https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate. So, Viktor, your comment doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the translate method wrong. The translate method needs a dict created by the maketrans method.

```py
output = ("abcdefabc").translate(str.maketrans("abc", "123"))
```

Thre print will read out: 123def123

Answer (score 1):

I guess You're using `Python3`, since this is valid syntax in `Python2`. For `Python3`, use following:

```
import os
def rename_file():
    file_list = os.listdir(r"C:\Users\Sushant\Desktop\test")
    print(file_list)

    for file_name in file_list:
        os.rename(file_name, file_name.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "0123456789")))

rename_file()
```

And here's the docs for [maketrans](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) function.

Answer (score 0):

When using `translate()` you have to pass in a table made by `maketrans()` as the first argument. This is the reason for getting a `TypeError` since you are passing in `None`.

With `maketrans()` you pass in the character you want to change in one string. The second argument is a string with the character you want to put in their place. This function returns a table, which you then pass into `translate()`.

In your case something like this would work.

```
file_name.translate(str.maketrans("", "", "0123456789"))
```

Further reading on [maketrans()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm) and [translate()](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_maketrans.htm)